# How to make a configurable design in restaurant delivery problem?

Tags: design, coding-style

The problem is like there are few restaurants and few delivery guys available. Each restaurant has a meal order and the delivery guys are to be assigned to the restaurant.

Now there may be many criteria for assignment of the guy to a restaurant. For example, the distance between delivery guy and restaurant, the priority of customer who places an order like a premium customer, the time of placement of the order etc.

How can code design be made to easily add new conditions?

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering.SE... expect research before asking](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a rules engine.

Comment: Thanks. It a great suggestion. I have seen something like this in my organization but it never clicked to me. Searching on this term will definitely help.